# Gatsby Error: Your site's "gatsby-node.js" created a page and didn't pass the path to the component

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I coult only find one other post on stackoverflow on this question. Any help would be great! I have been following the tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fqImaAnPNvA) to try to use Gatsby with GraphQL. But I keep getting the error:

> ERROR #11322
>
> Your site's "gatsby-node.js" created a page and didn't pass the path
> to the component.
>
> The page object passed to createPage: {
> "path": "/blog/technical-seo-with-graphcms",
> "componenent": "/Users/ela/Yao/Dev/paper-plane-project/src/templates/BlogPosts.js",
> "context": {
> "post": {
> "id": "ckadrcx4g00pw01525c5d2e56",
> "title": "Technical SEO with GraphCMS",
> "slug": "technical-seo-with-graphcms",
> "tags": [
> "SEO"
> ],
> "author": {
> "id": "ckadqepn400gv0108p4debydk",
> "name": "Jesse Martin"
> }
> }
> } }

Here is my gatsby-node.js:

```js
const path = require(`path`);

exports.createPages = async({graphql, actions: {createPage}}) => {
    const {data: {gcms : { posts }}} = await graphql(`
     query {
        gcms {
            posts (stage: PUBLISHED) {
                id
                title
                slug
                tags
                author {
                    id
                    name
                }
            }
        }
    }
    `);

    // const posts = pageQuery.data.gcms.posts

    const blogTemplates = {
        Article: path.resolve('./src/templates/BlogPosts.js'),
      }

    posts.forEach(post => createPage({
        path: `/blog/${post.slug}`,
        componenent: blogTemplates.Article,
        context : {
            post : post,
        }
    })
  );
}
```

And Here is my BlogPosts.js template file:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { graphql } from 'gatsby';

const BlogPosts = (props) => {
    const { post } = props.post;
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <h1>{post.title}</h1>
        </React.Fragment>    
    
)};

export default BlogPosts;
```

Any help would be awesome. I truly cannot find anything on the web for this error.

Comment: You spelled `component` incorrectly as `componenent` in `createPage`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your `createPage` function. You typed `componenent` instead of `component`. Should be:

```
posts.forEach(post => createPage({
    path: `/blog/${post.slug}`,
    component: blogTemplates.Article,
    context : {
        post : post,
    }
})
```

In addition, if you check the [repository provided in the tutorial you mentioned](https://github.com/notrab/graphcms-gatsby-source-graphql/blob/master/gatsby-node.js) you can find the full configuration.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad to help. If there's anything else that I can help with, please let me know. Otherwise, I would ask you to close the issue,